# Bundle from Static LIbrary

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have added a subproject as a static library to my main project.

Now, on the main project I am trying to load something that is on the bundle of the subproject. Something like this:

```
NSString *defaultStorePath =
[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"database" ofType:@"sqlite"];
```

but this is returning nil...

how do I solve that?

Comment: What about `[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:...]` with the CFBundleIndentifier of your sub-bundle?

Comment: I have not created this bundle in particular. Where do I find the bundle identifier? Simple things are complex on Xcode.

Comment: Is "database.sqlite" copied to the application bundle? Where exactly is it located inside the bundle?

Comment: database.sqlite is copied to the bundle. It is inside MyBundle/MyBundle/coredata/database.sqlite

Comment: Is there a .plist file in the bundle? If yes, does it contain a key CFBundleIdentifier?

Comment: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/ios-library-with-resources/ Could you try to init the bundle by name instead ? Xcode doesn't create resources bundle for libs automatically, browse your main bundle content (either on device or at `iPhone Simulator` dir) to make it clear which files you have there, note `iPhone Simulator` might contain the files that you've already removed from the project.

Comment: @A-Live - you are right. Resources are not included on static libraries by default (**thanks Apple**). The link you provided contained the solution. Please make this an answer so I can accept and close this! Thanks!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Oh well, as I'm not the article author I think it will be more fair if you give your conclusion as an answer and accept it, please don't forget to quote the link there so that others can check it as well.

Comment: There's also an alternative, instead of using separate bundle you can create a build phase of the final application that will copy lib resources into the main bundle, either a `Copy Files` or `Run Script` with `ditto` will work fine. Disadvantage is that there might be conflicts and you'll get lot of files at the root of main bundle, separate lib bundle helps you organize it better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A-live gave the answer, but he is too modest to post it here as an answer.

Here is the link with the answer
http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/ios-library-with-resources/

The problem was exactly because resources are not included when you create a static library.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this..

```
    NSString *resourceBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]       
                   pathForResource:@"StaticLibrary" 
                                       ofType:@"bundle"];

    NSBundle *resourceBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:resourceBundlePath];
```

Now, you can use this resourceBundle as your static Library Bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and in my case even bundleWithIdentifier returned nil for some reason. If nothing else works you can always try to iterate over all files like below. That worked for me.

```
[self urlForResource:@"database.sqlite"];

// ...

- (NSURL *)urlForResource:(NSString *)resource
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *directoryURL = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]].bundleURL;
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [fileManager enumeratorAtURL:directoryURL includingPropertiesForKeys:nil options:0 errorHandler:^BOOL(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
        return YES;
    }];

    for (NSURL *url in enumerator)
    {
        NSString *lastPathComponent = [[url absoluteString] lastPathComponent];
        if ([lastPathComponent isEqual:resource])
            return url;
    }
    return nil;
}
```